# Regular expression that returns two dates

Tags: regex, date

I'm struggling in creating a regex that given this string:

`20  - 29 APR 2017, 9  nights`

returns two groups, first:

`20 APR 2017`

and second:

`29 APR 2017`

Comment: What is your flavor? Which language are you in? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(\d+).*
```

And replace by:

```
$1 $3 $4\n$2 $3 $4
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/13)

Comment: Thanks  but I cannot use substitution, I need two groups as a result